# Use replace in rule

Tags: replacement, rule

I would like to define two rules: one for the material and thickness the second one for volume and mass

```
rule1={t->1/2,row->1000};
rule2={v->t^3,m->v*row};
```

now if I used the following:

```
rule2/.rule1={v->1/8,m->v*1000}
```

how to replace v in rule2 to get the following:

{v->1/8,m->125}

Comment: Why not just use `Set` and allow MMA to do the substitutions for you: `t = 1/2; row = 1000; vv = t^3; mm = vv row; Thread[{v, m} -> {vv, mm}]`

Comment: Somewhat convoluted: `ReplacePart[rule2, 2 -> (rule2[[2]] /. rule2[[1]])] /. rule1`

Comment: I dont want to set the parameters to values because I am not sure what is the material that I'll be using (design problem). But after conducting the full study I will replace all parameters by the appropriate values. @MelaGo

Comment: @BobHanlon , one issue in your method that I may not know the location of m or t in my actual code. The above is just example of what I want.

Comment: `(rule2 /. rule1) /. (lhs_ -> rhs_) :> (lhs -> (rhs /. (rule2 /. rule1)))`

Comment: I would turn your rules into equations (e.g. `Equal@@@rule1`) then use `Solve`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ReplaceAll[rule1] @ MapAt[ReplaceAll[rule2], rule2, {All, 2}]
```

> ```
> {v -> 1/8, m -> 125}
> ```

Comment: What changes do I need yo do to the above code to work with Mathematica 7 ?

Comment: @LoveEva, try `ReplaceAll[MapAt[ReplaceAll[#, rule2] &, rule2, {All, 2}], rule1]`  or `MapAt[# /. rule2 &, rule2, {All, 2}] /. rule1`.